# Godox X Pro with Olympus FL-700WR

Tags: flash, olympus, godox

Does anyone know if you can use the Godox X Pro Trigger to fire the Olympus FL-700WR flash without having a receiver on it's foot? If so can you tell me how to set up the two units. Many thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. Though both systems use the 2.4 GHz radio band, their communication protocols are completely incompatible with each other.

In addition, while Godox does make X1R receivers for Canon, Nikon, and Sony, at this time, they do not make a four-thirds compatible receiver, so if you were to add a Godox receiver to the foot of the FL7600WR, you would only have sync: no TTL, no HSS, no remote power control.

The flash has to be in the same system as the transmitter, if you don't want to be stacking triggers or using add-on receivers (Olympus FR-WR or Godox X1R). You either need to bite the bullet and get the Olympus FC-WR transmitter to use with the FL600WR, or add a Godox 2.4 GHz speedlight to your bag to use with an XPro-O/X2T-O, or Flashpoint R2 Pro II-O.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot. Godox uses their own wireless communication protocol which is not compatible with the Olympus flash.

The only way around that is to use one of Godox receiver/transceiver units under said flash.